# How to avoid errors with perl command line parameters and use strict

Tags: perl, command-line

Why is it that my code is not working after I added `use strict; use warnings;`? Is there a way to make it work?

Previously, the working code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s
print "x: $x\n";
print "y: $y\n";
```

The command that I ran is `perl -s test.pl -x="hello" -y="world"`. The output is:

```
x: hello
y: world
```

However, after I added `use strict; use warnings;`, I got the following errors:

```
Variable "$x" is not imported at test.pl line 4.
Variable "$y" is not imported at test.pl line 5.
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 4.
Global symbol "$y" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 5.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I know I need to declare `my $x` and `my $y` to fix the 3rd and 4th error. But what does the first 2 errors mean and how do I overcome it?

Comment: I devote an entire chapter in _Mastering Perl_ to your options (heh) here. :)

Comment: the shebang line is wrong; it should be #!/usr/bin/env perl  then use strict; on a new line for maximum portableness

Comment: @briandfoy Would that be Chapter 10 of _Mastering Perl_: 'Configuring Perl Programs'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a a rudimentary switch parser `perl -s`, which uses global variables. To make it work with `use strict` you need to refer to the globals: `$main::x` as ruakh pointed out.

But even so, lexical variables (declared with `my`) are preferable in just about all cases. Just do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($x, $y) = @ARGV;
print "x: $x\n";
print "y: $y\n";
```

And use with:

```
perl test.pl hello world
```

For a more detailed and switch like handling, check out the [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aLong) module.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't notice "-s" in my rush. +1

Comment: Re: "I doubt it is compatible with `use strict`": It is. See my answer below for how. :-)

Comment: Sheer luck, I'm dead on my feet. =)

Comment: If you are going to discard -s, the solution isn't to make lexical variables (which are really just file scoped globals in this case, which might as well be global variables in a single file program). Now you have to parse the options yourself. You could use one of the Getopt modules, but -s is often handy when you don't want to go that far.

Comment: @briandfoy Really? To me, the `-s` switch seems like one of those many arcane functionalities that still remain in perl here and there. Feels rather a lot like finding skeletons in old spooky castles. "Oops, look what someone left here ages ago." And what's this "handy when you don't want to go that far"? Either you write something properly, or you don't. If it's a throw-away script, nobody cares about switches. If it's something to be kept a while, why not do it properly?

Comment: I haven't used `-s` before and am pleased to find out about it, but I've often wished for something a bit quicker to set up than Getopt::Long. Almost any script can benefit from switches, and if there's a way to use them that's easy to program, that will fit a certain class of scripts. If you have more time, great, use Getopt::Long which is very good. 

But Perl scales right down from enterprise software to 10-minute, 5-minute, 1-minute and 10-second jobs. Somewhere in there, `-s` could be useful. TIMTOWTDI !

Answer (score 9):

Actually, declaring these variables as lexical (`my`) variables will not help, because it's too "late": the `-s` switch will already have set them. It sets the *global* (package) variables (in your case, `$main::x` and `$main::y`, or — as a special shorthand — `$::x` and `$::y`). If you don't want to have to refer to them using their package-qualified names, then you can use an `our` declaration to indicate that the bare names `$x` and `$y` refer to the `$x` and `$y` in the current package:

```
our ($x, $y);
print "x: $x\n"; 
print "y: $y\n";
```

*(Hat-tip to derobert for pointing out that you can use `our` for this.)*

Alternatively, you can copy the global variables into identically-named lexical variables:

```
my ($x, $y) = ($::x, $::y);
print "x: $x\n";
print "y: $y\n";
```

This will take care of both sets of diagnostics.

Comment: @derobert: You're quite right; I have tested, and have shamelessly stolen that for my answer. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

To understand what ANY Perl error/warning means, you can refer to [`perldiag`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eflora/perl-5.14.2/pod/perldiag.pod).

Specifically, for "is not imported", it says:

> Variable "%s" is not imported%s
>
> > (W misc) With "use strict" in effect, you referred to a global variable that you apparently thought was imported from another module, because something else of the same name (usually a subroutine) is exported by that module. It usually means you put the wrong funny character on the front of your variable.

Basically, Perl made 2 distinct guesses about your un-declared identifyer `$x` - it was either

1. a package-scoped global that is prohibited from being used under `strict` ("Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package")
2. or it was an attempt to use another package's variable that ought to have been imported but wasn't ("Variable "$x" is not imported").

Perl can not tell WHICH of the two theories are correct, so spat out both possibilities. The latter error (Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name) was the correct one in this case - it WAS a global variable in your original pre-strict code.